# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: while trying to execute tests through Selenium, ChromeDriver and Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Guys Please Help Me in The Morning it Was Working Fine Suddenly While i Was Running Test, it asked Me a Popup to Allow Access. Why i Dont Know. First i Cancelled That Pop up after again i Run The Test and Gave Access. From That Time Chrome Driver is Not Opening.

[image: img]

Error Stack Trace :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: E:\Workspace\xxxxxxxxx\â€ªâ€ªC:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\chromedriver.exe
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:121)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:116)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$0(ChromeDriverService.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:116)
at Lead.FinalTest.beforeTest(FinalTest.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:616)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Looks like a 'cut-and-paste' problem with your single quotes and now it can't find the driver. Try moving it to a location without spaces.

Comment: @radimpe Sorry Man! i Cant Get it What Your Saying. Can You Show an Example of What Your Saying?

Comment: According to me, you have to reinstall chrome browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As error says, there is no executable driver exists in the path you have written.

1. Make sure, that driver still exists in the path.
2. Try to replace driver(if exists) in another folder and change path in the code
3. Reinstall driver and set new path in the code

***PS:*** this is not a valid location:

```
E:\Workspace\xxxxxxxxx\â€ªâ€ªC:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\chromedriver.exe
```

Comment: Ok Fine, I'll Try With Reinstalling The Driver and Check it!

Answer (score 3):

put chrome driver at
`C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\chromedriver.exe`
and set same path in code   `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\chromedriver.exe");`

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: E:\Workspace\xxxxxxxxx\â€ªâ€ªC:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\chromedriver.exe
```

...implies that the *JVM* was unable to find the **ChromeDriver** in the effective location as per the configuration mentioned within your code.

As per your code trial, you have mentioned the location of the *ChromeDriver* as:

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\chromedriver.exe
```

But when your *testcase* gets executed the effective location is considered as:

```
E:\Workspace\xxxxxxxxx\â€ªâ€ªC:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\chromedriver.exe
```

So, there are some configuration within your *code block* or *IDE configuration* or *OS PATH variable* which modifies the *absolute path* of the *ChromeDriver* binary. Addressing this issue will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Man! Got It !

Comment: @koushick Glad to be able to help you !!! Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.

Comment: May i Know How To Check Which Issue Came Because of This?

Comment: @koushick Because of this issue the _JVM_ was looking at the wrong place for the _ChromeDriver_ and on being unsuccessful throws an error as **`IllegalStateException`**

Comment: Sorry to Ask Again Man, How To Change it's Path.

Comment: @koushick it will be tough to guess how the _os path_ **E:\Workspace\xxxxxxxxx\â€ªâ€ª** is getting appended to the desired _os path_ **C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\chromedriver.exe**. Most possibly some configuration within the config file within your project.

Answer (score 1):

This problem problem caused by special character in your path - f.e. some folder name contains 'ą' or 'ś' or space

Comment: it is better to provide full solution