# Getting “The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property”though set correct path

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My code is very simple code:

```
 package Automation;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class FirstTestCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/Jagman/Downloads/chromedriver");
        WebDriver wd = new ChromeDriver();

        String url = ("https://www.google.com/");

        wd.get(url);
```

have downloaded and added jar as "Java 3.13.0" from selenium hq site. Download Google Chrome Driver-2.29 from the same website and located it in "/Users/Jagman/Downloads/chromedriver" path.

When I run the above code I getting an error as " `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:738)".`

Getting version error though did proper configuration. so kindly help me for fixing the issue. Details: OS: Mac.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message: "'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path)

Comment: check at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607304/java-lang-illegalstateexception-the-driver-executable-does-not-exist-while-try/51608734#51608734

Answer (score 0):

add .exe in chromedriver path :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/Jagman/Downloads/chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: Hey Dangi13, I added the .exe to the chromedriver, but the error is still occurring.

Comment: try to give full absolute path like : C://Users//Jagman//Downloads//chromedriver.exe

Comment: How do I find the exact path a Mac OS ?