# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable must exist error using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, illegalstateexception

I am unable to execute my first selenium code. Tried changing webdriver path several times but that didn't work.

Code trials:

```
package Learningday1;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class FirstScript {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "‪‪‪C:\\Users\\amann\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        driver.get("https://selenium.dev");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable must exist: C:\Users\amann\eclipse-workspace\Selenium learning 2.0\???C:\Users\amann\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Require$FileStateChecker.isFile(Require.java:342)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:147)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:39)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:233)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:437)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:49)
    at Learningday1.FirstScript.main(FirstScript.java:10)
```

Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some ambiguity between your code trials and the error stacktrace.

In your code you mentioed the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) as:

```
‪‪‪C:\\Users\\amann\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe
```

Where as the error stacktrace mentions the driver executable doesn't exists at:

```
C:\Users\amann\eclipse-workspace\Selenium learning 2.0???C:\Users\amann\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe
```

---

### Solution

Ensure that you have unzipped the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744026/7429447) and placed with the sub-directory:

```
C:\\Users\\amann\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32
```

and you need to mention the absolute path within the [System.setProperty()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60061951/7429447) line as:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "‪‪‪C:\\Users\\amann\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
```

---

### Update

You have 2 projects with almost similar names, a maven project and another a Java project. The name starting with ***Selenium learning***.

Try to avoid same name for multiple projects and blank spaces within the project names. Example *`SeleniumTest`*, *`SeleniumProgram`*, etc.

PS: You may opt to delete the current project and create a new one.

---

### References

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: while trying to execute tests through Selenium, ChromeDriver and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51608925/7429447)

Comment: Yes i had unzipped it and also checked again that it has been unzipped and there's no copy of it

Comment: but i created this project because the earlier one was too giving same error that had maven dependencies, and this one too giving same error i don't know why, please help

Comment: Possibly _blank spaces within the project name_ is causing all the issues. Delete the unwanted one.

Comment: Thank you so much dear, it worked. Thanks for the help, now i can learn selenium. Once again thank you.